# UTF-8 Error when trying to insert a string into a PostgresQL BYTEA column with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I have a column in a PostgresQL table of type BYTEA.  The model class defines the column as a `LargeBinary` field, which the documentation says "The Binary type generates BLOB or BYTEA when tables are created, and also converts incoming values using the Binary callable provided by each DB-API."

I have a Python string which I would like to insert into this table.

The Python string is:

```
'\x83\x8a\x13,\x96G\xfd9ae\xc2\xaa\xc3syn\xd1\x94b\x1cq\xfa\xeby$\xf8\xfe\xfe\xc5\xb1\xf5\xb5Q\xaf\xc3i\xe3\xe4\x02+\x00ke\xf5\x9c\xcbA8\x8c\x89\x13\x00\x07T\xeb3\xbcp\x1b\xff\xd0\x00I\xb9'
```

The relevant snippet of my SQLAlchemy code is:

```
    migrate_engine.execute(
        """
        UPDATE table
        SET x=%(x)s
        WHERE id=%(id)s
        """,
        x=the_string_above,
        id='1')
```

I am getting the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (DataError) invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x83
'\n            UPDATE table\n            SET x=%(x)s\n            WHERE id=%(id)s\n            ' {'x': '\x83\x8a\x13,\x96G\xfd9ae\xc2\xaa\xc3syn\xd1\x94b\x1cq\xfa\xeby$\xf8\xfe\xfe\xc5\xb1\xf5\xb5Q\xaf\xc3i\xe3\xe4\x02+\x00ke\xf5\x9c\xcbA8\x8c\x89\x13\x00\x07T\xeb3\xbcp\x1b\xff\xd0\x00I\xb9', 'id': '1',}
```

If I go into the pgadmin3 console and enter the UPDATE command directly, the update works fine.  The error is clearly from SQLAlchemy.  The string is a valid Python2 string.  The column has type BYTEA.  The query works without SQLAlchemy.  Can anyone see why Python thinks this byte string is in UTF-8?

Comment: no idea, what happens if you make it a raw string? As in r"\x83\x8a..."

Comment: Then the slashes would be in the string.  I get the same problem with a single character string like `'\xa9'` (the copyright symbol).  Something, somewhere, is trying to decode it as UTF-8.  The last line in the stacktrace shows "sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 331, in do_execute"

Comment: Is it the placeholder substitution that's doing it? The `"""` string is presumably UTF-8 and then you're trying to embed non-UTF-8 data inside it using simpleminded string operations. You might need to manually handle the ASCII-ification of the binary data to do it that way (or maybe there's a %-code that will do it for you, not a Python guy, sorry). PostgreSQL supports a couple different encoding schemes for embedding binary data in strings, maybe try one of those.

Comment: Could it be the  client_encoding settings? Just spitballing here...

Comment: @muistooshort That may be.  For plain string interpolation that is not the case, e.g. `len("""abc%sdef""" % '\xa9')` produces 7 as expected, sans errors.  However the `execute` method may do its own brand of interpolation.  For now an extra base64 encoding is a sufficient workaround, but it will slow things down :(

Comment: Can you check the query logs to see if the database is getting just a single big nasty string for the UPDATE rather than something with "real" placeholders and bound parameters? I'm pretty sure you'd have to [hex-encode or escape-encode](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html) that `bytea` value to get anything useful to happen, I don't think a raw `\x00` null byte would be valid inside SQL. Is there a binary-specific %-code that will hex-encode things?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the  data in a [`buffer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer):

```
migrate_engine.execute(
    """
    UPDATE table
    SET x=%(x)s
    WHERE id=%(id)s
    """,
    x=buffer(the_string_above),
    id='1')
```